# Qual a "função" no Oracle equivalente a um "set Generator"?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Eu gostaria de saber, qual o comando no `Oracle` seria equivalente ao

```
SET GENERATOR GEN_ID_TABELA TO 5;
```

(comando feito no `FireBird`)

Porque eu gostaria de criar um script com os `inserts`, porém para não ocorrer erros na aplicação depois, acredito que eu deva setar em que sequência/posição a `SEQUENCE` esta. (Exemplo, fiz 5 `inserts` na tabela, então a `SEQUENCE` será 5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo a documentação da Oracle a forma de alterar o valor seria excluir e depois recriar com o valor iniciar que você deseja.

```
DROP SEQUENCE GEN_ID_TABELA

CREATE SEQUENCE GEN_ID_TABELA
  START WITH 5;
```

> Documentação da Oracle:
>
> [CREATE SEQUENCE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm)
>
> [DROP SEQUENCE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_9001.htm#BGECFFGA)
>
> [ALTER SEQUENCE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_2011.htm#i2228022)

Comment: Assim, agora entendi. Realmente é diferente do firebird. Obrigado !